# How to record a dropdown item which opens when clicked on the image?

Tags: testing, automation, sahi

In my application I have logout link as it is in gmail account. I have to click on a dropdown image to see the logout link, this is not recording when I am trying to record using sahi tool and I am not able to record the browse and upload event using sahi tool.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can record the items by hold the ctrl button and mouseover the particular item the sahi controller will show the element name in the Accessor text box . Copy that script and paste it in your script file and try to run